# Perca de valor no getIntent()

Tags: android, android-activity, intent, broadcastreceiver, android-alarmmanager

meu problema é o seguinte...
tenho uma rotina de notificações que ao usuário clicar na notificação da tela, abrir uma nova Activity. Nessa nova Activity eu mostro algumas informações que busco no banco de dados dependendo do código que passo por parâmetros, porém, não estou conseguindo recuperar esse código na nova Activity.

Vou colocar as classes para explicar melhor:

Essa classe abaixo eu chamo assim que faço a inserção da notificação no banco de dados:

```js
public class AlarmUtilSessao {    

    // Agenda o alarme com repeat
    public static void scheduleRepeat(Context context, Intent intent, long triggerAtMillis, long intervalMillis, int id) {
        intent.putExtra("ID_SESSAO",id);
        PendingIntent p = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, id, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarme = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarme.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerAtMillis, intervalMillis, p);
    }   
}
```

No meu Manifest eu chamo por receiver a classe que faz a notificação:

```css
<receiver android:name=".Lembretes.LembreteSessao">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name=".Alarm.Lembretes.LEMBRE_SESSAO" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

A minha classe que é disparada pelo receiver é essa abaixo. Eu recebo corretamente o ID e trabalho com ele no banco de dados:

```js
public class LembreteSessao extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "Sessao";
    public static final String ACTION = ".Alarm.Lembretes.LEMBRE_SESSAO";
    

    String currentTime, currentDate, newDate, newTime;
    int Ano, Mes, Dia, Hora, Minu;
    Date time, date;
    SimpleDateFormat timeFormat, dateFormat;
    JN_26_Alertas horarioModel;


    //CLASSE CHAMADA PELO MANIFEST NO HORARIO DO ALARME
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ctx = context;
        codigo = intent.getIntExtra("ID_SESSAO", 0);

        Intent notifIntent = new Intent(context, lembrete_sessao.class);//alterar

        notifIntent.putExtra("ID_SESSAO",codigo);        
        NotificationUtil.create(context, 3, notifIntent, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "Sessao", "Verifique a Sessao");

        //new Thread() {
          //  public void run() {
                //...Acessos e manipulações do banco de dados
        //    }
        //}.start();
        notifIntent.putExtra("TIME", currentTime);
    }
```

Até aqui o sistema recebeu e passou corretamente valores por putExtra e getIntExtra, porem, ao clicar na notificação apresentada na tela do celular, o valor chegar na próxima tela vazio:

```js
public class lembrete_sessao extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener,
        DialogInterface.OnClickListener{

    private TextView                    horaReceita;
    private int                         codigo, idRem = 0, qtd = 0;;
    private ListView                    lista;
    private JN_65_RemedioSessaoAdapter  remedioSessaoAdapter;
    private List<JN_25_RemedioSessao>   listRemSessao = null;
    private String                      msgSMS = null;
    private RadioButton                 Whats, Messenger, SMS, Nenhum;
    private String                      ConfiguracaoAlarme = null, Time = null;
    private ArrayList<Integer>          codArrayRemedio = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    private AlertDialog                 alertConfirmacao;
    private EditText                    foneSMS;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lembrete_sessao);
        codigo = 0;
        codigo              = getIntent().getIntExtra("ID_SESSAO", 0);
        Time                = getIntent().getStringExtra("TIME");
      
      //****
```

A variável TIME também chega nula, porem, nem é de tanta importância... se eu conseguir pegar o valor do código eu posso recuperar o valor TIME no banco de dados... alguma sugestão? E Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1):

Tente assim:

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras == null) {
    id_sessao = null;
} else {
    id_sessao = extras.getString("ID_SESSAO");
}
```

Comment: usar o Bundle tanto pra passar quanto pra receber?

Comment: Sim, usa o Bundle pros dois, a diferença é que pra passar é **putExtra** e pra receber é **getExtra**.

Comment: Pior que nao deu tambem ...

Comment: Faça um outro aplicativo simples com apenas duas telas, tente passar os parâmetros entre elas e nos diga o que acontece.